# Basic rule to store User ID into another table as foreign key in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

As a beginner I thought that it would be easy to store current user session ID into another table as I managed to get the user ID into Line_Items table however I believe that I have not understood the basic principle of storing one primary key into another table as a foreign key which in my case is trying to store session User_ID into Carts table as a cart belongs to a user and user has many cart. Any code or any helpful link regarding this question will be greatly appreciated. Following are my models. Please let me know if any other code is needed for assistance. Thanks:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :role, :subscriber, :name 


has_many :line_item
has_many :cart


class NotAuthorized < StandardError; end
end
```

Cart.rb:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :user_id

has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user

def add_phone(phone, current_user = nil)

  current_item = line_items.find_or_initialize_by_phone_id(phone.id)

  current_item.increment!(:quantity)
  current_item.phone.decrement!(:stock)
  current_item.user = current_user
  current_item.phone.save
  current_item
end

# returns true if stock level is greater than zero
def can_add(phone)
    phone.stock > 0
end

# returns the total number of items in a cart
def number_of_items
    total = 0
    line_items.each do |item|
        total += item.quantity
    end 
    total
end

def empty?
    number_of_items == 0
end

def grand_total
    grand_total = 0
    line_items.each do |item|
        grand_total += item.quantity * item.phone.price
    end 
    grand_total
end

end
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I actually have no idea at all how to get the primary key into another table as foreign key in ruby on rails.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your relationship declaration.. they should be plural, try that and see if it helps, also you should have an user_id on your carts & line items models.

```
has_many :line_items
has_many :carts
```

Comment: Thanks for that but apparently I don't have any code which will add current session ID into cart table. That is what I need help with. If you could either help me with that or give me any related link that would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: I see, well, basically, what you should try is to setup an before_filter maybe on some Controller, on that before_filter action, you can then create then you could setup a cart and save its Cart ID to the session (which will push the cart id on to the customer to their session). then whenever the user hits back one of your controllers look for that Cart ID in its session, and just load the Cart  using that ID. You would need to create a Cart model with some basic stuff, such as Content (serializable Hash maybe?), user_id integer, and any other fields you think you might need, I hope that helps

Comment: my cart actually works fine, it adds products into line_item table and also displays it in the view, it also counts and multiplies to show the total. It would be great if you could edit your comment and give me a typed out example which would help a lot :) If you need any other code that I have to assist you, I can update that on my post. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

In **User** model

```
has_many :line_items
has_many :carts
```

Also in line **Item** and **Cart** model, you can mention:

```
belongs_to :user
```

We can mentioned it using :foreign_key as well given below:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id"
```

Hope it will be helpful for you..

For getting session ID or for saving the records in your cart controller or line items controller

**For LineItem**

```
#In create action
@line_item = current_user.line_items.build(params[:user])
# or
@line_item.user = current_user
```

**For Cart**

```
#In create action
@cart = current_user.carts.build(params[:user])
# or
@cart.user = current_user
```

For getting `user id` in your controller for finding related `line_items and cart` you can simply get it by `current_user.id`

In controllers or views for session id you can use as below

```
session['session_id']
```

Thanks.

Comment: that sounds great but what methods do I need to write for carts controller and models to get the session user id into carts table. I already have the current_user method which works fine. How do I get that session ID into carts table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the further help. My Application is really weird. The code you provided isn't storing the user id into carts table. Wierd thing I was talking about is that when I delete the create action in cart controller, it still creates a record in the table. Would you like to see the whole code for model and line item model or any controller?

Comment: which controller would you like to see? The application doesn't display any error at all and doesn't either store user_id into carts table

Comment: I need your controller where you are trying to fetch session id or saving the records...